# How to stop graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter from printing logs in case of exception?

Tags: java, logging, graphql, graphql-spqr, graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter

Could someone please help me on how to avoid printing stack trace in graphql in case exception happens (e.g. sending invalid id to find a record or creating a record without sending a mandatory field)?

I'm using graphql-spqr-spring-boot-starter and getting logs printed in case invalid data is sent. Below are the screenshots:

[image]

Eclipse console:
[image]

Anyone's help will be much appreciated. Thanks!